# How to extract a value from a json string?

Tags: python, json, string

Im having to use this json module for an assignment for python https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json
And I can't figure out how to extract the "llcontinue" value from something like  this example string https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=langlinks&list=&titles=tallinn&lllimit=10

The idea is to get it and then run a function again and from that json string to get the language values.

Comment: Include your attempt and error that you got in the question. Hint: You should use `json.loads()`. And read [ask]

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some code using the module and explain what, if any, errors you're getting?

Comment: Might also be worth having a look at the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for guidance on what to include in a question.

Comment: I really dont know where to even start, how does json.loads() work? Like if I gave it the string as a param aka something like json.loads(theLongString, object_hook="llcontinue")? Which just gives a "'str' object is not callable" error since it's not actually an object..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hope, you're right, `json.loads()` works in your example, though I'm not sure how the `object_hook` option works or if it would even be necessary. This should do what your asking:

```
import urllib, json
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=langlinks&list=&titles=tallinn&lllimit=10'
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print data['continue']['llcontinue']
```

output:
`31577|bat-smg`

With this you should be able to get the language values you're after.

Comment: Yup that's it, was just really confused, didn't realise that what you get from json.loads() is a dict and then it was just a matter of looking up nesting dictionaries. Thanks